# Was my polygon inserted correctly into the database?

Tags: mysql, database, geospatial

```
mysql> show create table places\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: places
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `places` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `name_full` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `network_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fence_ll` polygon NOT NULL,
  `fence_utm` polygon NOT NULL,
  `area` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `network_id` (`network_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `places_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`network_id`) REFERENCES `networks` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

This is my query:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO places(name, fence_ll, fence_utm, area, created_at) 
VALUES('West Covina',
   GeomFromText('POLYGON(( 34.08166844698419 -118.01307678222656,33.994611584814606 -118.01307678222656,33.994042291874415 -117.89566040039062,34.08280585343835 -117.89634704589844)) ', 0), 
   GeomFromText('POLYGON(( 406532.3562310586 3771674.3531455416,406436.8059323749 3762021.032807315,417280.6563504976 3761856.9033192885,417303.43441323494 3771699.900605784)) ', 0), 105355675, 1471220285)
```

The command inserts the record correctly, but for some reason `fence_ll` and `fence_utm` are blank.

```
*************************** 5. row ***************************
        id: 11
      name: Los Angeles
 name_full: NULL
network_id: NULL
  fence_ll: 
 fence_utm: 
      area: 6859688899
created_at: 1471220285
updated_at: NULL
```

My worry is that the `polygon` points are too precise. If so, to what decimal places should I truncate the points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the first and last points of your polygons are not the same, and this seems to be a requirement.  Try this instead:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO places(name, fence_ll, fence_utm, area, created_at)
VALUES
    ('West Covina',
     GeomFromText('POLYGON(( 34.08166844698419 -118.01307678222656, 33.994611584814606 -118.01307678222656, 33.994042291874415 -117.89566040039062,34.08280585343835 -117.89634704589844, 34.08166844698419 -118.01307678222656 )) ', 0),
     GeomFromText('POLYGON(( 406532.3562310586 3771674.3531455416,406436.8059323749 3762021.032807315,417280.6563504976 3761856.9033192885,417303.43441323494 3771699.900605784, 406532.3562310586 3771674.3531455416 )) ', 0), 105355675, 1471220285)
```

[**Reference**](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23900/how-to-add-polygon-in-mysql-database)

Comment: Thanks Tim. Do the digits matter (should I truncate it)? Will it affect performance?

Comment: @TIMEX I don't know about precision, but my _guess_ is that the worst which will happen is that you will get truncation (or maybe rounding).  You should verify the polygon precision rather than assume it can handle 14 digits of precision.